# Determining the operation of a direct product of a group?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory

I am asked to list the elements of $\Bbb Z_2$ x $\Bbb Z_3$.

I find that when I use the operation defined under $\Bbb Z_2$, my group is not closed, and that got me thinking:

How do I determine the operation of a direct product group?

Comment: A direct product of groups only has one operation, it's the *notation* that's additive.

Comment: @Travis Okay, I understand that. But how do I determine the operation of the direct product group if the groups I am using both use distinct operations? Do I use whichever one works, define a new one, or is there some approach I take?

Comment: Given groups $(G, \ast)$ and $(H, \star)$, the operation $\odot$ on $G \times H$ is, by definition, $(g, h) \odot (g', h') := (g \ast g', h \star h')$, that is, you just use the $G$ operation on the $G$ factor and likewise for $H$.

Comment: If the operation on $A$ is $\ast$ and the operation on $B$ is $\circ$, then the operation on $A \times B$ is defined by $(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2) = (a_1 \ast a_2, b_1 \circ b_2)$.

Comment: Thank you both for your clarification